# Transitivity of Wilcoxon signed-rank test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have performed Wilcoxon signed-rank tests for variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, where it appears that (speaking informally) $X < Y < Z$. Indeed, the p-value for the one-sided Wilcoxon signed-rank test for $X$ vs $Y$ is $p_{X<Y} = 8 \cdot 10^{-3}$, and that for $Y$ and $Z$ is $p_{Y<Z} = 4 \cdot 10^{-6}$. Yet I have $p_{X<Z} = 3 \cdot 10^{-4}$.

Clearly $p_{X < Z} \nless \min(p_{X<Y},p_{Y<Z})$, but what sort of relationship is guaranteed to hold? I would think that $p_{X < Z} \le \max(p_{X<Y},p_{Y<Z})$. Is this in fact the case? And is there something stronger that one can say?

Comment: You're doing signed rank tests on three sets of pair-differences? Is this with complete data (no missing values anywhere)?

Comment: @Glen_b - yes and yes!

Comment: I'm not even sure you necessarily have transitivity in the population version of the one-sample Hodges-Lehmann statistic (median Walsh-average) on pair-differences across three populations. If you don't then p-values might end up anywhere.

Comment: You do have transitivity.

Comment: ... at least in large samples, by the look of it. +1

Comment: Actually, I'm no longer convinced about transitivity, but the rest holds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: I'm no longer convinced that the ordering is transitive, but it *is* still described by the pseudomedians.  It's just that when you don't have a location shift the pseudomedians need not be additive: you don't necessarily have $m_{XZ}=m_X-m_Z$, so $m_{XZ}=m_{ZY}-m_{YZ}$. I think everything else holds -- because most of the results below are negative rather than positive.

We can think in terms of the estimated pseudo-medians and their standard errors.

If the distributions are continuous and differ only by location shift, not in shape or scale, then the large-sample distributions of the pseudo-medians will be $N(m_i,\sigma^2/n)$ for $m_X$, $m_Y$ and $m_Z$ pseudo-medians and the same $\sigma^2$.  Since $\hat m_Z-\hat m_X=(\hat m_Z-\hat m_Y)+(\hat m_Y-\hat m_X)$, the $X:Z$ $p$-value will be smaller than the minimum of the other two *if* the other two are both less than 0.5 (so that the pseudomedians are ordered the right way).

When the distributions differ in scale or shape it's more complicated, because the $\sigma^2$s will differ.  For example, if $Y$ is less variable than $Z$ and $X$ it's a lot easier to get the $p$-values not to be ordered the way you want.  For example, consider

```
r<-replicate(1000,{x<-rnorm(500)
y<-rnorm(500,0.15,s=0.1)
z<-rnorm(500,0.4)

c(wilcox.test(x,y,paired=TRUE)$p.value,
wilcox.test(y,z,paired=TRUE)$p.value,
wilcox.test(x,z,paired=TRUE)$p.value)})

table(r[3,]<pmin(r[1,],r[2,]))
table(r[3,]<pmax(r[1,],r[2,]))
```

You get quite a few examples where $p_{XY}>p_{XZ}>p_{YZ}$ even with all the $p$-values less than 0.5.

However, if $\hat m_X\sim N(m_X, \sigma^2_X/n)$ in large samples (and similarly for $Y$ and $Z$), we know that the variance of $m_X-m_Y$ is $(\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y)/n$ (and similarly).

Now, $\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Z$ is not necessarily less than  $\max\{\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y, \sigma^2_Y+\sigma^2_Z\}$, so we might not expect even to have $p_{XZ}<\max \{ p_{XY}, p_{YZ}\}$, but it's going to be a pain to prove.

Simulation to the rescue:

```
> set.seed(2023-9-18)
> r<-replicate(10000,{x<-rnorm(500)
+ y<-rnorm(500,0.1,s=0.1)
+ z<-rnorm(500,0.2)
+ 
+ c(wilcox.test(x,y,paired=TRUE, alternative="less")$p.value,
+ wilcox.test(y,z,paired=TRUE, alternative="less")$p.value,
+ wilcox.test(x,z,paired=TRUE, alternative="less")$p.value)})
> which(!(r[3,]<pmax(r[1,],r[2,])))
[1] 1420 1745 2226 3959 5440 6158 9463 9844
```

Now:

```
> r[,1420]
[1] 0.4756392 0.5053687 0.6037722
```

Nope: one is bigger than 0.5

```
> r[,1745]
[1] 0.6671444 0.6444861 0.6835040
```

Nope: they are all bigger than 0.5

```
> r[,2226]
[1] 0.2439124 0.2258590 0.2484954
```

Success: it is possible to have $p_{XZ}<\max \{ p_{XY}, p_{YZ}\}$.  The constraint does seem to be *almost* true, but not quite.

I think any sharp results will have to be on the Normal-approximation scale rather than on the $p$-value scale.

Answer (score 2):

Does this meet the conditions of a counterexample? Or have I misunderstood something somewhere?

```
x <- c(3.51, 3.75, 3.914, 4.118, 4.77, 6.31, 6.53, 9.59, 15.117, 14.301)
y <- c(3.29, 3.32, 3.413, 3.66, 3.78, 10.143, 10.22, 10.31, 11.88, 12.4)
z <- c(0.01, 0.55, 5.22, 6.11, 7.115, 7.94, 8.48, 9.51, 10.503, 11.604)

wilcox.test(x,y,"less",paired=TRUE) # p-value = 0.6523
wilcox.test(y,z,"less",paired=TRUE) # p-value = 0.7217
wilcox.test(x,z,"less",paired=TRUE) # p-value = 0.7842
```